# Почему браузер кеширует заголовок о переадресации?

Tags: php, nginx, кэширование

Включил кеширование в nginx:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(js|css|png)$ {
    expires max;
}
```

Всё работает. Дальше возникла проблема: неавторизованных пользователей на сайте переадресовывает на главную страницу, а после входа пользователь получает доступ ко всем страницам. Самое странное, что браузер (Chrome, если это важно), кеширует заголовок о переадресации. В итоге при попытке открыть ту самую страницу, я вижу status code `302 Moved Temporarily (from cache)`. То же происходит и с успешно загруженными страницами – status code у некоторых `200 ok (from cache)`. Как заставить браузер кешировать только js, css и png, но не кешировать страницы?

Comment: Для начала показать весь конфиг nginx, а так же все заголовки которые отправляются с сервера при переадресации неавторизованных пользователей

Comment: @AlexeyTen представьте себе самый банальный конфиг nginx – вот это и есть мой конфиг.

Comment: Я не буду ничего представлять. Я прошу показать _ваш_ конфиг.

Comment: @AlexeyTen хорошо, вот все конфиги http://pastebin.com/gPX8VVwb, а вот заголовки http://pastebin.com/L1mxTKr8

Comment: Ищите эти заголовки в своих PHP скриптах. В nginx ничего нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen в самих скриптах я не устанавливал кеширование вообще. Но менял в php.ini session.cache_limiter и session.cache_expire, т.к. они вызывали отрицательную дату в expires-заголовке (1981 год). А так больше ничего не менял :/

Comment: «Я ничего не менял, только менял кеширование» http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: @AlexeyTen оказывается, cache_limiter можно отключить, установив none. Спасибо за отклик.